# When I echo session variable getting expected output but when I use it in if condition it's not. I want know the reason for this strange result

Tags: php, session

```
echo $_SESSION['area'];
```

> output:Hello;

```
if($_SESSION['area'] == 'Hello'){  
    echo 'Working Fine';  
}else{
    echo "Not Working";  
}
```

> output:Not Working

I trying to find the reason for this strange result.

Comment: Seems like there's likely more in the string than you're seeing.  What happens when you output the *length* of the string?

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['area']);`

Comment: Is the semicolon at the end of the first output a typo? If it's part of the output string, that's your problem.

Comment: you are right, my actual value of session variable is "All" and the result is string(7) may I know the reason for it,

Comment: $_SESSION['area'] = $_POST['area'] //All
when I echo var_dump($_SESSION['area']; // string(7)
var_dump($_POST['area']); // string(3) why is like that, why it's varying its length?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you got that result because session may not have set

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Set session variables

$_SESSION["area"] = "Hello";

if($_SESSION['area'] == 'Hello'){  
    echo 'Working Fine';  
}else{
    echo "Not Working";  
}
?>
```

Comment: But for this code i got output like 'Working Fine' give a try Suresh

Comment: $_SESSION['area'] = $_POST['area'] //All
when I echo var_dump($_SESSION['area']; // string(7)
var_dump($_POST['area']); // string(3) why is like that, why it's varying its length if you know the reason please share?

Comment: For both echo and var_dump i am getting result like string(5) "Hello" string(5) "Hello" if i give input like Hello I am confused with the reason why are u getting like string(7) and string (3)

Answer (score -1):

store your session into variable like this

```
$area=$_SESSION['area'];
```

and use it like

```
if($area == 'Hello'){  
    echo 'Working Fine';  
}else{
    echo "Not Working";  
}
```

Comment: $_SESSION['area'] = $_POST['area'] //All
when I echo var_dump($_SESSION['area']; // string(7)
var_dump($_POST['area']); // string(3) why is like that, why it's varying its length if you know the reason please share?

Comment: Down voted because `$_SESSION` is a variable. Assigning a var ($_SESSION['area']) to a var ($area)  is pointless and then testing it, is needless.